# Whatsapp on Ubuntu Mobile

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Do you know if there is some Whatsapp client on Ubuntu for mobile phones? I would want to use it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a WhatsApp plugin for Pidgin. But you have to get the password of your WhatsApp account. Read [this](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/05/how-to-sniff-the-whatsapp-password-from-your-android-phone-or-iphone/) to learn how.

**EDIT:** As noted in a comment, this doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: But could they block the account for not using official software?

Comment: How should they notice?

Comment: I don't know... perhapts official Whatsapp sends a command or something like that... Anyway I'll try and will tell you.

Comment: It no longer works. WhatsApp changed their security protocols.

Answer (score 3):

According to this http://www.whatsapp.com/download/  their is no App for Ubuntu Mobile Yet

[image]